# Mount VHD of Vista in Windows 7 RC

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, vhd

How can I mount Vista .vhd file on Windows 7 RC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Launch Computer Management and right-click the Disk Management node - select Attach VHD, browse to the file and click OK.

As for booting vhd, you can only do that with Windows 7 or Server 2008 R2 vhds.

Answer (score 0):

Note that Virtual PC VHD's are incompatible with Windows 7 VHD's.  Nobody has provided a good explanation as to why. But therefore you can't create one in VPC and boot to that, either.

Kinda sucks, cuz I wanted to boot to the .NET 4.0 CTP VPC VHD and couldn't for that reason. If you created this VHD with VPC, good luck.